# Can I change the text in an input field without changing the value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Is it possible?

And if so, it is probably considered bad practice right?

**Edit**

I mean this: The value of an input field is usually identical to the text displayed in the input field. I wonder if there is a way to sepperate the two...

Comment: What do you mean by changing the text?

Comment: Do you want the `placeholder` attribute? Hard to tell what you're really asking...

Comment: Inputs do not have a `.text()`, only a value that can be changed with `.val()`

Comment: For `placeholder` use `placeholder="Default text"`. FYI.

Comment: Since this question is closed I will leave my best guess here: I think what you're trying to do is just to apply a mask in your input, a possible solution (probably not the best) would be adding the mask on the input value, and then remove the mask on value update, or when you think it's necessary to not have the mask anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about `<INPUT>` fields: no.

You could write javascript to change the value before the form submits, however.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a single `<input type="text">` form element, no. However, it should be possible to style an element to look like an input box, display whatever text you like, and post back a different value using an `<input type="hidden">` form element instead.

I honestly can't see any useful reason for doing that though.

Comment: `I honestly can't see any useful reason for doing that though.` I find it really weird that in 2012 there was no valid reason for using input masking

Comment: @CaptainPrinny My interpretation of the question (lacking in detail as it is), both then and now, makes it sound like something completely different to input masking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jquery's `.data()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: How would this work to solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you tell us why you are trying to do that?
If you want a default value when the page is loaded you can use the placeholder function, but when the user goes to enter a value, the placeholder will disappear.

**CODE**

```
<input type="text" value="[MUST BE EMPTY TO SHOW THE PLACEHOLDER]" placeholder="Placeholder goes here" />
```